# Building and installing NodeJs on Gentoo Linux distribution

Tags: linux, node.js, gentoo

i'm trying to build Nodejs from my Gentoo Linux distribution but i get the following error:

```
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): {task... etc.}
```

I've tried many tutorials or commands but i'm no server administration expert. Has anyone succesfully isntalled nodejs on Gentoo ? If yes, what were the commands do did pass ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's impossible to tell without emerge --info and the missing build log (and then you should also build with MAKEOPTS="-j1" if possible).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you may want to try a "testing" version of a package if the stable does not  build. It's safer to avoid packages that are not stable, but in a pinch you can try:

```
emerge flaggie
flaggie net-libs/nodejs -- +~amd64 # or ~x86
emerge =net-libs/nodejs-0.10.26 # works for me^tm
```